# saving, loading expandable listview checkbox states to shared preferences - there must be a better way

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, performance

basically, i have an expandable listview with checkboxes that i want their states saved to shared preferences. The method that i'm implementing works, but i have a feeling that it is not all that it could be. I wouldn't be surprised to see it crash. Basically with my method, I load and save the states in my activity class with serialization.

```
SharedPreferences settings3 = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);    
        try {
            check_states = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(settings3.getString("CBSTATES", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

some more code in between.

```
protected void onStop() {
            SharedPreferences settings3 = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = settings3.edit();
            try {
                editor3.putString("CBSTATES", ObjectSerializer.serialize(check_states));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            editor3.commit();
        }
```

To get the arraylist from my actual expandable adapter, I have it instantiated as a static variable and transfered. in my espandablelistadpater class -->

```
//  set checkbox states
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> check_states = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    public void setChildrenAndValues() {
        //initialize the states to all 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int j = 0; j < children[i].length; j++) {
                tmp.add(0);
            }
            check_states.add(tmp);
        }
    }
```

And here is the getChildView

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater childInflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View childView = childInflate.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_childview, parent, false);

        TextView childtxt = (TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicschildtv);
        childtxt.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        //      Load the checkbox states        
        setChildrenAndValues();

        final CheckBox childcb = (CheckBox)childView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicchildchkbox);

        if (check_states.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition) == 1) {
            childcb.setChecked(true);
        }else{ childcb.setChecked(false);
        }

        childcb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (childcb.isChecked()) {
                    check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, 1);
                }else{ check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        return childView;
```

I just wanted to know if i was doing everything alright, or if i was missing a step cause I can actually feel the slow-down, especially when deserializing. Perhaps i should do this in another thread (whatever that means). Am i using static variables in the correct way cause i'm altering them in both directions. maybe i'm missing an if null statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayLists have a CAPACITY, that you can set explicitly when declaring/initializing an instance; a Default applies if you don't specify a capacity.

Whenever the number of elements grows beyond the capacity, that capacity is reset. I haven't worked with ArrayLists, but assuming they behave as similar collections, growing beyond the capacity results in increasing the capacity to a larger value, then allocating space for the new capacity, and then copying all the values from the 'old' smaller storage to the new one.

I guess, this is what's slowing down your code: the repeated copying of ever larger amounts of data, everytime the capacity is increased.

To verify (and remedy): try to initialize your arraylists - using the constructor that takes an integer as argument for the initial capacity - with the size they will eventually take, i.e. children.length

Comment: i can't believe i overlooked that. i guess i'm gonna have to give it to you. it helped significantly, though not to what i was expecting. perhaps it was working with an arraylist of an arraylist, i will try revising that also.